# rbegin() in std::list is never equal to an iterator pointing into the list?

Tags: c++, list, stl

Why does the following code crash?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


std::list<int> aList={1,2,3,4,5};

std::list<int>::reverse_iterator i=aList.rbegin();
i++;
i++;

assert(*i==3);//assertion passes as expected


while (i!=aList.rbegin()) { //never becomes false
      aList.pop_back(); //segmentation fault

}
assert(*(aList.rbegin())==3);

return 0;
}
```

I assume rbegin will eventually equal to *i* and stop the loop; however not happening.

Note I did following workaround, still curios whats the wrong with the above code in first place

```
size_t  differance =std::distance( aList.rbegin(),i);

while (differance >0) {
    aList.pop_back();
    differance--;
}
assert(*aList.rbegin()==3);
```

Comment: Please don't mix container names with variable names

Comment: `while (differance >0) {` is not a work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::list::rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/rbegin) returns an iterator that refers to the sentinel end-of-list node, but dereferences to the value stored in the prior node (5 in your case).  This behavior applies to any reverse iterator of an `std::list`: the node you get a value from when dereferencing it a reverse iterator is the node prior to the node the iterator is actually pointing at.

Visualize it like this, in terms of which element is referenced by iterators:

```
rend() <-------- rbegin()
  |                 |
  1     2 3 4 5   (end)
  |                 |
begin() --------> end()
```

This means that the iterator that dereferences to the value 3 is *actually internally referring to the element with the value 4.*  When the value 4 is removed from the list, the iterator value stored in `i` becomes invalidated, and at that point you can't reason about its behavior.  It's likely to be (and should be) not equal to every other iterator.

You can verify for yourself that this is the case by writing out the value of `*(i.base())` when `*i == 3`.  You will see that `*(i.base()) == 4`.

So your problem is not that `rbegin()` iterators are "never equal to an iterator pointing into the list," your problem is that you are removing the element that the iterator was internally pointing to and then trying to compare that now-invalidated iterator to `rbegin()`.

Consider using `aList.erase()` instead of your loop.  Since you want to remove from the element with the value 4 to the end of the array, `i.base()` already gives you an iterator that you can pass directly to `aList.erase()`:

```
aList.erase(i.base(), aList.end());
```

Comment: Ok So rbegin.base() == end()

Comment: @MalMa Yes, precisely. And when it comes to invalidation of reverse iterators, a reverse iterator `i` is invalidated when the forward iterator `i.base()` is invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have it all reversed ,incrementing a reverse iterator moves it backward.

and `pop_back()` will invalidate an iterator to the last element, hence a segfault in your loop. You should do a `pop_front()` and check for `(i !=rend())`

Comment: pop_front ? I want to remove all elements past *i*  i.e. 4,5